# NullPointerException thrown whilst accessing a multi-dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a game which requires you to place blocks, similarly to Minecraft. But, I have been getting some trouble from trying to make a multidimensional array which will store the x and y coordinates of the block placed. The code for this is as follows;

```
public Block[][] blocks = new Block[maxBlockX][maxBlockY];
```

It is giving me a null pointer exception. The exception is below;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.lojana.src.World.loadWorldAsReg(World.java:16)
    at net.lojana.client.SpriteCraft.display(SpriteCraft.java:45)
    at Run.main(Run.java:5)
```

It is quoting the following method `loadWorldAsReg()` in my World class. The method is here.

```
public void loadWorldAsReg() {
    for (int x = 0; x < maxBlockX; x += 20) {
        for (int y = 0; y < maxBlockY; y += 20) {
            blocks[x][y].draw();
        }
        }
}
```

It is also quoting the following method.

```
public void draw() {
    getTexture().bind();
    shapes.drawSquare(new Point(x, y), new Point(x + 20, y + 20));
}
```

Does anyone have an idea as to how to solve this peculiar error?
Much appreciated!

Comment: What line is it 'quoting' in each of those methods ? And what are `maxBlockX` and `maxBlockY` defined to be?

Comment: Line 16 of the class `World` is `blocks[x][y].draw();`

Answer (score 3):

Your array is full of `null`s.

You need to create a `Block` instance for each element in the array first.

Comment: How can I do that? Would I make a for loop running through the whole array setting the value to a chosen block?

Comment: Thank you so much SLaks! :D -- It won't let me accept though?!

Comment: @user1921838: Just wait ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
public void loadWorldAsReg() {
    for (int x = 0; x < maxBlockX; x += 20) {
        for (int y = 0; y < maxBlockY; y += 20) {
        blocks[x][y] = new Block();
        blocks[x][y].draw();
    }
    }
}
```

Call the constructor before using the object. I have used the default constructor `Block()` assuming your code has one. Include the parameters if any needed by the constructor. :)

Comment: Ummm... When I am trying to do the code you specified, it is only drawing it once, now for as long as I want it to?!

Comment: Didn't get you. Do you think you need a [Java Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) ?

Answer (score 0):

Writing `Block[][] blocks = new Block[maxBlockX][maxBlockY]` will create a two dimensional array of size maxBlockX * maxBlockY that contains only nulls.

The new DATA_TYPE[size1][size2] will only fill in default values for PRIMITIVE data types. So new int[2][1] will create an array [[0],[0]] and new Block[2][1] will create [[null],[null]].

Just initialize your Blocks properly and you will be set.

```
Block[][] blocks = new Block[maxBlockX][maxBlockY];
for (int i=0; i<blocks.length; i++)
  for (int j=0; j<blocks[0].length; j++)
    blocks[i][j] = new Block();
```

You can also avoid drawing bad (null) data by having a check in your loadWorld function. This also might make your life easier, dunno:

```
public void loadWorldAsReg() {
  for (int x = 0; x < maxBlockX; x += 20) {
    for (int y = 0; y < maxBlockY; y += 20) {
      if (blocks[x][y] != null)
        blocks[x][y].draw();
    }
  }
}
```